# How to build multi dimensional array for store this?

Tags: php

I want to store information like below with a key like key = activity window then other info under it, then another key etc..

```
key: 'activity window'
name: 'Recent Activity'
iconCls: 'activity'
module: 'activity-win'
```

any idea how to put this into a multi dimensional array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    'activity window' => array(
        'name'    => 'Recent Activity',
        'iconCls' => 'activity',
        'module'  => 'activity-win'
    )
);
```

Is this what you're looking for, or have I completely misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$myArray = array(
    'activity window' => array(
        'name' => 'Recent Activity',
        'iconCls' => 'activity',
        'module' => 'activity-win',
    ),
    array(
      ...
    ),
);
```

You can also add on to the array:

```
$myArray['new key'] = array(
    'name' => 'New Name',
    'module' => 'New Module',
);
```